# UK standard visa without bank statement

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

My sister is a British citizen. She has invited me to see her family in the UK and has sent all required documents. She is able to bear all my expenses as she works as architect and her job is well paid. The problem is that I have no bank statements to present to the embassy. Should I apply without bank statements?

Comment: Be careful with your application. The visa officer will need to be convinced that you are just visiting the UK will return to India when you say you will, rather than staying in your rich sister's house forever. You will need to demonstrate strong ties to India (I assume that's where you live), and such ties are usually financial and familial.